# How to use generics in props in React in a functional component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, react-props

In a class based component, I can easily write some code like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

interface IProps<T> {
    collapsed: boolean;
    listOfData: T[];
    displayData: (data: T, index: number) => React.ReactNode;
}

class CollapsableDataList<T> extends React.Component<IProps<T>> {
    render () {
        if (!this.props.collapsed) {
            return <span>total: {this.props.listOfData.length}</span>
        } else {
            return (
                <>
                    {
                        this.props.listOfData.map(this.props.displayData)
                    }
                </>
            )
        }
    }
}

render(
    <CollapsableDataList
        collapsed={false}
        listOfData={[{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}]}
        displayData={(data, index) => (<span key={index}>{data.a + data.b}</span>)}
    />,
    document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

Actually this `CollapsableDataList` component should be a functional component because it's stateless, but I can't figure out how to write a function component and use generics in props, any advise for me?

Comment: **See Also**: [Functional React Components with Generic Props in TypeScript](https://wanago.io/2020/03/09/functional-react-components-with-generic-props-in-typescript/)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You can't create a functional component with a type annotation and make it generic. So this will NOT work as `T` is not defined and you can't define it on the variable level:

```
const CollapsableDataList : React.FunctionComponent<IProps<T>> = p => { /*...*/ }
```

You can however skip the type annotation, and make the function generic and type `props` explicitly.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

interface IProps<T> {
    collapsed: boolean;
    listOfData: T[];
    displayData: (data: T, index: number) => React.ReactNode;
}
const CollapsableDataList = <T extends object>(props: IProps<T> & { children?: ReactNode }) => {
    if (!props.collapsed) {
        return <span>total: {props.listOfData.length}</span>
    } else {
        return (
            <>
                {
                    props.listOfData.map(props.displayData)
                }
            </>
        )
    }
}


render(
    <CollapsableDataList
        collapsed={false}
        listOfData={[{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, c: 4}]}
        displayData={(data, index) => (<span key={index}>{data.a + (data.b || 0)}</span>)}
    />,
    document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

Comment: I'm worrying about some HOC require you pass component which has explicit type (like `ComponentClass` or `FunctionalComponent` type), and then those functional components which don't have a type annotation won't pass the type check. (not test yet)

Comment: @hronro Typescript uses structural typing, so the parameters of the function are more important than the declared type. You will still have problems with HOCs, because Typescript does not have higher order types. So the type parameter will get lost when you pass it to the HOC. But that is a general generic component issue, not so much a type annotation issue.

Comment: I know it's not in the question either but it seems to me that when rendering `CollapsableDataList`, one should add a generic type like `{a: number; b: number}`, to better illustrate the benefit of being able to provide one. (Also, is there a particular reason for the optional children?)

Comment: @AndyO I just copied the `children` definition from react definitions I think. Adding the generic type parameter while possible is not necessary, `T` will be inferred. I always prefer to let the compiler do inference when it can.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Right, I missed that the type can be inferred here, thanks! (I also like to use TS' inference capabilities as much as possible)

Comment: You can use PropsWithChildren<IProps<T>> and get rig of interface intersection

Comment: Thank you! Been searching for this for awhile, don't want to go back to class component unnecessarily.

Answer (score 32):

The type `React.FC` is essentially this:

```
<P = {}>(props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any) => ReactElement | null
```

so instead of this (which isn't allowed):

```
const Example: React.FC<Props<P>> = (props) => {
  // return a React element or null
}
```

you can use this:

```
const Example = <P extends unknown>(props: PropsWithChildren<Props<P>>): ReactElement | null => {
  // return a React element or null
}
```

For example:

```
const Example = <P extends unknown>({ value }: PropsWithChildren<{ value: P }>): ReactElement | null => {
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(value)}</pre>
}
```

Or, more strictly, if the component doesn't use the `children` prop and won't return `null`:

```
const Example = <P>({ value }: { value: P }): ReactElement => {
  return <pre>{value}</pre>
}
```

then use the typed component as `<Example<string> value="foo"/>`

Answer (score 30):

```
type Props<T> = {
    active: T;
    list: T[];
    onChange: (tab: T) => void;
};

export const Tabs = <T,>({ active, list, onChange }: Props<T>): JSX.Element => {
    return (
        <>
            {list.map((tab) => (
                <Button onClick={() => onChange(tab)} active={tab === active}>
                    {tab} 
                </Button>
            ))}
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: Notice the dangling , inside <T,> this fixes a bug with the compiler and allows using a simple generic.

Comment: Any more info on why the dangling `,` is needed and what bug it fixes?

Comment: TypeScript seems to think that <T> is the opening tag of a component named "T" in ".tsx" files that use JSX for React components.

To move beyond this default interpretation of the transpiler to that of generics, the comma can be introduces as mentioned by @MatLipe as <T,>

Comment: When I am trying this, I am getting `This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'ReactNode', but multiple children were provided.` near ` <Button onClick={() => onChange(tab)} active={tab === active}>
                    {tab} 
                </Button>`

Comment: This did it for me. The other responses are way too over engineered.

Answer (score 20):

React 18, Typescript 4.6.3

```
interface IProps<T> {
  data: T[];
}
export const YourComponent = <T,>(props: IProps<T>) => {}
```

**Usage**:

```
const App = () => {
  const data : IDataProps[] = [
    {
      id:"1",
      label:"first banu"
    }
  ]
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <YourComponent data={data}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: how to use this `YourComponent`?

Comment: What is  the 2nd omitted type here <T,> ?

Answer (score 14):

Before addressing the functional component, I assume the original code example is missing the generic in JSX component as I don't see it passed to the `IProps` interface. I. e.:

```
interface Ab {
  a: number;
  b: number;
}

...

// note passing the type <Ab> which will eventually make it to your IProps<T> interface and cascade the type for listOfData
return (
<CollapsableDataList<Ab>
  collapsed={false}
  listOfData={[{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, c: 4}]}
  ...
/>
)
```

Ok now with a little effort you actually can have a functional component with generic props.

You are stuck using 'modern' syntax though as it employs an assignment and arrow function which is of no use for your generic case:

```
// using this syntax there is no way to pass generic props
const CollapsableDataList: React.FC<IProps> = ({ collapsed, listOfData }) => {
  // logic etc.
  return (
  // JSX output
  );
}
```

Let's rewrite the variable assignment as a good old `function`:

```
// we are now able to to write our function component with generics
function CollapsableDataList<T>({ collapsed, listOfData }: IProps<T> & { children?: React.ReactNode }): React.ReactElement {
  // logic etc.
  return (
  // JSX output
  );
}
```

The `children` workaround is not necessarily needed if the component does not use the children prop but I've added it to highlight the fact that it has to be retyped manually as `React.FC` did that for us before.

Answer (score 2):

supplement for #1.

If you want to export component as FunctionComponent and pass eslint displayName error.

you can do it bellow.

```js
const yourComponentWithLowerCase: <T>(props: PropsWithChildren<Props<T>>) => ReactElement | null = (props) => {
  // code
}

export const YourComponentWithUpperCase = yourComponentWithLowerCase;
(YourComponentWithUpperCase as FunctionComponent).displayName = 'something'
```

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62705164/803349) is a good example since it properly defines the props and the return type of the function.

As an alternative these can be defined as functions instead of arrow functions.  This gets around the need to extend the prop type to hint to the TS compiler that this not a react component.

```
export function CollapsableDataList<T>(
  props: PropsWithChildren<IProps<T>>
): ReturnType<FunctionComponent<IProps<T>>> {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a Simple Custom Button Component using **React Native**, showcasing a scenario of using generics with props in a **React Functional Component**.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Pressable, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';

export type ButtonType = 'filled' | 'outline';

interface IButtonProps<T extends ButtonType> {
  type: T;
  onPress: () => void;
  filledText?: T extends 'filled' ? string : never;
  outlineText?: T extends 'outline' ? string : never;
}

const CustomButton = <T extends ButtonType>({
  type,
  filledText,
  outlineText,
  onPress,
}: IButtonProps<T>) => {
  return (
    <Pressable
      style={
        type === 'filled' ? styles.filledContainer : styles.outlineContainer
      }
      onPress={onPress}>
      <Text style={styles.textContainer}>{filledText || outlineText}</Text>
    </Pressable>
  );
};

export default CustomButton;

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  filledContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 16,
    backgroundColor: '#0096FF',
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  outlineContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 16,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#0096FF',
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  textContainer: {
    color: '#191970',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: '500',
    fontSize: 22,
  },
});
```

*For React.js users you will have to only change the JSX of the above code snippet accordingly.*

> Lets call the Custom Button Component by setting a type which will conditionally take in only the attributes related to a specific type or else a type error is shown.

```
<CustomButton
  type="filled"
  onPress={() => Alert.alert('Pressed')}
  filledText="Filled"
 />
```

[image]

```
 <CustomButton
   type="outline"
   onPress={() => Alert.alert('Pressed')}
   outlineText="Outline"
  />
```

[image]