# Define props with generic type in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using React with TypeScript in the following way:

```
interface MyComponentProps {
    ...
    ...
}

const MyComponent:FunctionComponent<MyComponentProps> = props => {
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Now I need to define the following props type:

```
interface MyComponent2Props<T> {
    prop1: T,
    ...
}
```

I tried to define the component:

```
const MyComponent2<T>:FunctionComponent<MyComponent2Props<T>> = props => {
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

But this is incorrect syntax.

What is the correct way to define such component?

Comment: I don't have the rep to comment, but this is what I've found:
[How to use generics in props in React in a functional component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53958028/how-to-use-generics-in-props-in-react-in-a-functional-component)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const MyComponent2 = <T>(props: SomeProps): FunctionComponent<MyComponent2Props<T>> => {}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try something like this:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

interface Props<T> {
  a: T;
}

const Component = <T extends {}>(props: Props<T>) => {
  return <div>{props.a}</div>;
};

function App() {
  return <Component a="testing" />;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

You can [view the example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-react-prop-generic-j082n).

Note the `extends {}` is necessary in a `tsx` file. See: [What is the syntax for Typescript arrow functions with generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308370/what-is-the-syntax-for-typescript-arrow-functions-with-generics)