# Using Typescript generics for React Functional Components with eslint props validation

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to create a functional component in React using Typescript, and I have already set it up according to [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53958028/how-to-use-generics-in-props-in-react-in-a-functional-component):

```js
export interface CustomProps<T extends object> extends SomeOtherProps<T> {
  customProp?: number;
}

const CustomComponent: <T extends object>(props: CustomProps<T>) => JSX.Element = {
  customProp = 10,
  ...props
}) => {
  // etc
};
```

However, this gives me an error in `eslint` saying that the props are not validated:

> 'customProp' is missing in props validation

I can try to add props validation with the generic by adding `CustomProps` after the default props:

```js
export interface CustomProps<T extends object> extends SomeOtherProps<T> {
  customProp?: number;
}

const CustomComponent: <T extends object>(props: CustomProps<T>) => JSX.Element = {
  customProp = 10,
  ...props
}: CustomProps<any>) => {
  // etc
};
```

But this gives me a warning with "no explicit `any`". And if I insert `T`, it won't know about it. So how do I address this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution lies in instantiating the type again, just like it was instantiated for the component declaration itself:

```js
export interface CustomProps<T extends object> extends SomeOtherProps<T> {
  customProp?: number;
}

const CustomComponent: <T extends object>(props: CustomProps<T>) => JSX.Element = <T extends object>({
  customProp = 10,
  ...props
}: CustomProps<T>) => {
  // etc
});
```

This way, all props will be properly validated.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer Overview**

I thought I'd give a simplified answer that demonstrates the full use of TypeScript Generics in Functional React Components, since it took me a full day to figure out how to do this properly. The file extension is assumed to be ".tsx".

I demonstrate the Class-Based React Component equivalents first, so you can compare them.

This also demonstrates the access of sub-properties on types.

**Define Some Types That Will Be Used and Their TypeScript "typeof" equivalent checks:**

```
const isString = (x: any): x is string => typeof x === 'string';

interface A {
  a: string;
}
const isA = (x: any): x is A => !!x.a;

interface B {
  b: string;
}
const isB = (x: any): x is B => !!x.b;

interface Props<T> {
  thing: T;
}
```

**Simple Class-Based Component Example**

```
class ClassCompY<T extends A> extends React.Component<Props<T>> {
  render() {
    const { thing } = this.props;
    return <div>{thing.a}</div>;
  }
}
```

This is just here for comparison purposes.

**Complex Class-Based Component Example**

```
class ClassCompZ<T extends string | A | B> extends React.Component<Props<T>> {
  render() {
    const { thing } = this.props;

    if (isString(thing)) {
      return <div>{thing}</div>;
    }

    if (isB(thing)) {
      return <div>{(thing as B).b}</div>;
    }

    return <div>{(thing as A).a}</div>;
  }
}
```

This is just here for comparison purposes.

**Simple Functional Component Example**

```
const FuncCompA = <T extends A>(props: Props<T>) => {
  const { thing } = props;

  return <div>{thing.a}</div>;
};
```

**Complex Functional Component Example**

```
const FuncCompB = <T extends string | A | B>(props: Props<T>) => {
  const { thing } = props;

  if (isString(thing)) {
    return <div>{thing}</div>;
  }

  if (isA(thing)) {
    return <div>{(thing as A).a}</div>;
  }

  return <div>{(thing as B).b}</div>;
};
```

**Functional Component that takes React Children**

```
const FuncCompC = <T extends A>(props: Props<T> & { children?: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const { thing, children } = props;
  return (
    <>
      <div>{thing.a}</div>
      <div>{children}</div>
    </>
  );
};
```

You can append the `props: Props<T>` in any of the other components with `& { children?: React.ReactNode }` to allow them to use children as well.

**Calling all of the above components in JSX**

```
const WrapperComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ClassCompY thing={{ a: 'ClassCompY, Type: A' }} />
      <ClassCompZ thing='ClassCompZ, Type: string' />
      <ClassCompZ thing={{ a: 'ClassCompZ, Type: A' }} />
      <ClassCompZ thing={{ b: 'ClassCompZ, Type: B' }} />
      <FuncCompA thing={{ a: 'FuncCompA, Type: A' }} />
      <FuncCompB thing='FuncCompB, Type: string' />
      <FuncCompB thing={{ a: 'FuncCompB, Type: A' }} />
      <FuncCompB thing={{ b: 'FuncCompB, Type: B' }} />
      <FuncCompC thing={{ a: 'FuncCompC, Type: A' }}>ChildOfFuncCompC</FuncCompC>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Simply put this component in your app to see it working and to mess around with the components themselves to see what causes them to break. I only included the code that is strictly necessary not to break them.

**Leaving out "extends SomeType"**

TypeScript will complain about a sub-property like "a" or "b" not being found on the type "T".

**Leaving out "(something as SomeType)"**

TypeScript will complain about the types not matching up.