# Typescript: function with argument of enum type assigned to callback with argument type of string

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a dropdown component with a callback `onSelect:(option: string) => void`

I'm using it as a sort picker in one application, where the options are of enum type:

```
enum SORT_OPTIONS {
  LATEST = 'LATEST',
  OLDEST = 'OLDEST'
}
const onSortSelect = (val: SORT_OPTIONS) => {...}
<MyDropdown onSelect={onSortSelect} ... />
```

And typescript complains:

```
Type '(val: SORT_OPTIONS) => void' is not assignable to type '(option: string) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'val' and 'option' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'SORT_OPTIONS'.  TS2322
```

It's a bit counter-intuitive but makes sense, since in `MyDropdown` a string `option` will be passed to the `onSortSelect` callback, which requires an enum value.

**Question** is what is the best way to fix the types here? IMO both functions are typed correctly, `onSelect` should accept any string since `MyDropdown` can be used in any context. `onSortSelect` should only accept `SORT_OPTIONS`.

Currently I'm casting the type of onSortSelect: `<MyDropdown onSelect={onSortSelect as (val:string) => void} ... />` but it feels quite verbose

Comment: the `MyDropdown` is a third party components ? if not why don't you just change the callback type ?

Comment: Because MyDropdown is a generic component that should accept a callback that can use any string, not just SORT_OPTIONS. As I described, I don't think the typing is wrong with either function.

Comment: if it is generic why isn't it of type `(option: any) => void` ? PS: there is no solution here as it is a clearly a question of preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the types with Generics, no typescript error

```
enum SORT_OPTIONS {
  NEWEST='1',
  OLDEST='2'
}

interface DropdownProps<T extends string> {
  onSelect: (val: T) => void;
  options: T[];
}

const Dropdown = <T extends string>(props: DropdownProps<T> & {children?: React.ReactNode}) =>{
  const {onSelect, options} = props;
  return <select onChange={(evt) => onSelect(evt.target.value as T)}>
    {options.map(option => <option>{option}</option>)}
  </select>

};



const TestComp:React.FC = () => {
  const onSelect = (val: SORT_OPTIONS) => {
    switch (val) {
      case SORT_OPTIONS.OLDEST:
        console.log('old');
        break;
      case SORT_OPTIONS.NEWEST:
        console.log('new');
        break;
    }
  };
  const onSelect2 = (val: string) => {
    console.log(val);
  };
  return <>
    <Dropdown
      options={[SORT_OPTIONS.NEWEST, SORT_OPTIONS.OLDEST]}
      onSelect={onSelect}
    />
    <Dropdown
      options={['aaa', 'bbb']}
      onSelect={onSelect2}
    />
    </>
};
```

Note that

1. I can't type `Dropdown` with the regular `React.FC`, see the discussion here: [How to use generics in props in React in a functional component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53958028/how-to-use-generics-in-props-in-react-in-a-functional-component)
2. I have to do a type casting to the Generic type.

Please comment if you find a different conclusion from the link.

Answer (score 0):

Your callback deals with `onSelect:(option: string) => void`

This means that it passes **any** string to the handle, like: `hello`, `test`, and so on.

But your `const onSortSelect = (val: SORT_OPTIONS) => {...}` expects only **subset** of strings: LATEST, OLDEST.

So, TypeScript warns you that you can't pass the whole set to a function that expects subset.

To fix the issue, you need to update your `onSelect` handler to:

```
onSelect:(option: SORT_OPTIONS) => void
```