# How to use generics for differing React element props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

I am trying to implement the following (simplified version of my) code:

```
import React, { ReactElement } from 'react';

import { LegacyRef } from 'react';

export interface TestProps<T> {
  inputRef?: LegacyRef<T>;
  multiline?: boolean;
}

export const Test = <T,>({ inputRef, multiline }: TestProps<T>): ReactElement | null => (
  <>{multiline ? <textarea ref={inputRef} /> : <input ref={inputRef} type="text" />}</>
);
```

Here I want to be able to have two differing types of input shown depending on the multiline prop value. My plan was to do this using ts generics, passing the type of input (HTMLTextAreaElement or HTMLInputElement) when calling the component.

However, I can't seem to be able to get the transpiler to understand that the inputRef can take on more than one form, depending on what value is passed as a prop. I tried implementing the solutions provided on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53958028/how-to-use-generics-in-props-in-react-in-a-functional-component) as you can see in my code.

But I keep getting these errors on each respective `ref` line:

```
Type 'LegacyRef<T>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>'
Type 'LegacyRef<T>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement>'
```

Does anyone know of a solution to this particular problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You don't need generics, you want discriminated unions: https://tsplay.dev/m3XQbW

Comment: Using this approach I am getting the following error on the input element ref:

`Type 'string | ((instance: HTMLTextAreaElement) => void) | RefObject<HTMLTextAreaElement> | ((instance: HTMLInputElement) => void) | RefObject<...>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement>'.`

Comment: Hm? Is this in the playground or when you try to apply this method to your code?

Comment: This is in my code

Comment: That's weird... Can you update the question to include your attempt to integrate it with your project?

Comment: You mean integrating your suggestion to the project? Or my project configuration?

Comment: Ideally both. Maybe your TSConfig has something to do with it?